# Two CMS over one web site. Is that possible?

Tags: cms

Is it possible to maintain a web site or blog site using two CMS?

Comment: First thing I would be asking is why you need 2? Whole purpose of a CMS is to have a central location to control your website. Using 2 will eventually cause you headaches and problems....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to maintain a web site or blog site using two CMSes.

Comment: i'm gonna use pagelime and drupal is that feasible?

Comment: Sure.  Go for it!

Comment: If you're using Drupal, why do you need Pagelime?

Comment: yeah thanks for the question. i'm just a curious person. but i have something in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but I would recommend thinking about it twice as you will have 2x the code needed to manage in the future, you could need to do changes in the 2 CMS. Also it means 2x more CMS update, etc. If there is no other way, you can do it, but make sure it would not be possible with only 1 (possibly with plugins?).